# How do you create a domain-specific string class in .NET?

Tags: .net, string

Given that in .NET the `System.String` class is sealed, how do you create a simple domain-specific string class so you can use type checking to ensure that the correct *sort* of string is used? Do you have a favourite implementation of such a class?

You might, for example, want to create a class to represent an email address to ensure that email is not accidentally sent to someone's postal address. Although that's not a great example I'm thinking about the cases where all you need is the type safety but no additional logic or validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *wrap* the string class in one of your own and add all the type checking you want.

Think composition, instead of inheritance.

Comment: That's what I've been doing up to now (it's a good way to cut down the interface to what is appropriate, too), I'm asking because I'm throwing away all of the careful optimization that the `String` class has had, or in case I missed something.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're losing anything, especially if any operations are just going to go against the member String.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx in terms of your e-mail address example.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, my types are far more esoteric than that ;)

Comment: gotcha - well, if you're interested, you could always use Reflector on that class to get an idea of what's going on.